# dropwizard write log to remote server

Tags: dropwizard

I'm want to write to a log file in a remote server (over a local file which I've successfully wrote to).

in Dropwizard [documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#logging) there are only examples of how to write to a local file.

how do I instruct the application in the `yml` file?

Comment: By remote server you mean like writing the log files to another machine or sending the log messages to a remote application that consumes them for example via HTTP?

Comment: yes @AndréBarbosa exactly.

Comment: Which one @Igor: log files on a remote machine OR log messages sent to a remote application?

Comment: the first,  log files on a remote machine

Comment: Thanks @Igor. You should be able to achieve this by mounting a remote path (e.g. NFS or SMB) on the local file system. Then you just have to change the config in YML to point at the local mapped location. Makes sense?

Comment: thanks Andre, I'll definitely try that

Comment: @AndréBarbosa and if I want to send via http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it turns out, the request was to use greylog.

so here is the reference: [gelf](https://github.com/gini/dropwizard-gelf#logging-startup-errors-to-graylog)